# EIGRP vs OSPF: Opinion Based?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, site-content

Is the question [EIGRP vs OSPF](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147/protocols-eigrp-vs-ospf) primarily opinion based, (or at the very least, far too broad for this format), and therefore subject to closure?

The question in question:

> EIGRP and OSPF are both IGP protocols, the former is proprietary of
>   Cisco and the latter is an open standard. What are the benefits of
>   EIGRP over OSPF and vice versa?
>
> What protocol should one choose when deploying a network. If you have
>   mixed devices the choice would obviously be OSPF, but what if you are
>   running a Cisco only shop, are there any features EIGRP excels in
>   compared to OSPF that would make it feasible to only deploy EIGRP?

To date it has 4 answers and much commenting/discussion under each answer.

---

**Note:** The linked question, [EIGRP vs OSPF](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147/protocols-eigrp-vs-ospf), and it is the [4th Google Result](https://www.google.com/search?q=eigrp%20vs%20ospf) for "EIGRP vs OSPF"
and thus will bring search engine traffic to the site.